# how to duplicate the value of one form field in another in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form where a user can chose the applications he has access to? and when he the applications he wants access to, he is presented with more options. One of them is notification email address. if the user choses two applications, he gets two notification email address fields to fill. But both of them are stored in the same column in the database.

There are multiple fields like user authorisation level, user branch etc which are uniform accross all applications.

i am trying to replicate the value of one field in the other with jquery. i tried the below which obviously fails. Can anyone suggest how to acheive the replication?

```
$("#email").val().change(function() {       
    $("#email1").val($("#email").val());
});
```

Edit: I have drop down fields as well as text boxes.

Comment: Try just `$("#email").change(`.

Comment: how about if this is a dropdown field instead of a text field?

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.  Changing tag ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` returns a string which cannot have a change event. You need to use

```
$("#email").change(function() {       
    $("#email1").val($(this).val());
});
```

You will want to bind the change event using `on` or `live` depending on your version of jquery, if you haven't wrapped this piece of code in a `ready` block.:

```
$("#email").on("change",function() {       
    $("#email1").val($(this).val());
});
```

This fiddle shows setting a `<select>` tags value using `.val()` http://jsfiddle.net/8UG9x/

Comment: I also have dropdown fields. Will it work for dropdowns as well?

Comment: Yes and as long as your `<option>` elements have value attribute set val() will work.

Comment: see the api doc's on which elements `change` will bind to as well as examples of use: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

It is an often asked question:

[Copy another textbox value in real time Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698448/copy-another-textbox-value-in-real-time-jquery)

depending on when you need this action to execute, but if live

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#proname').live('keyup',function() {
        var pronameval = $(this).val();
        $('#provarname').val(pronameval.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KBanC/

another one, basically same:
[JQUERY copy contents of a textbox to a field while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160076/jquery-copy-contents-of-a-textbox-to-a-field-while-typing)

Comment: .live() is a deprecated function. Use .on()

Comment: ya sorry i just copied that, look at the second example