# Copying value of one textbox to another textbox return null

Tags: javascript, html

I need to copy a textbox value to another textbox. But .val() function of jquery isn't updating the provided values and returns empty/null.

I have tried all possible solutions including. Below is one link

[Copy another textbox value in real time Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698448/copy-another-textbox-value-in-real-time-jquery)

```
$("#textbox_2").focusout(function () {
        if ($("#textbox_1").val() == "Exception") 
        {
            $("#textbox_1").text("");
            $("#textbox_1").val($("#textbox_2").val());
        }        
        alert($("#textbox_1").val());
    });
```

[This is the output of textbox_1 value in alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQw0I.png)

I want to have value of textbox_2 in textbox_1. But it inserts null in textbox_1.

Comment: Is initial #textbox_1's value set to "Exception"? Can you show also html?

Comment: so it's empty `""` or `"null"`?

Comment: Your code seems to me to do exactly what it says it should do: https://jsfiddle.net/ukrf6jLz/

Comment: I think that `$("#textbox_1").text("");` make no effect, input is element without content inside it's self closing tag.

Comment: It's null. $('#textbox_1').val() at the end is null.

Comment: *`$('#textbox_1').val()` at the end is null* - please create working demo that demonstrates your issue (`[<>]` icon in editor), I see `.attr('value')` instead of `.val()` assuming that `hotel` is the real id of `textbox_1`

Comment: Note that a [mcve] will need to have some HTML in it. Provide a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @Jamiec - Yes it's same that i want and it is working fine on this jsfiddle but i copied same in my projects that stills returns null.

Comment: @user9950870 then, once again, provide a [mcve] and we'll try to help. But we cant see your project so cant help you.

Comment: @Jamiec , code is same as provided above. I am getting null in alert.

Answer (score -2):

> I need to copy a textbox value to another textbox.

Copying value of one textbox to another on blur with pure javascript:

```js
const source = document.querySelector('#source')
const destination = document.querySelector('#destination')

source.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  destination.value = e.target.value
})
```

```html
<input id="source" type="text" />
<input id="destination" type="text" readonly />
```